# Property of an almost additive sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

We say that a sequene of functions $\Phi=(\phi_n)_n$ is almost additive if there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that for every $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x\in \Lambda$ we have
\begin{equation*}
-C + \phi_n(x) + \phi_m(f^nx) \leq \phi_{n+m}(x) \leq C + \phi_n(x) + \phi_m(f^nx)
\end{equation*}

A proof I am trying to understand uses this to state that
\begin{equation*}
-Cm+ \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \phi_n \circ f^{nj} \leq \phi_{nm} \leq Cm+ \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \phi_n \circ f^{nj} 
\end{equation*}
but I cant quite see how they get see how they derive this. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Prove it by induction on $m$.  For $m = 1$, we have $$-C + \phi_n \leq \phi_{n} \leq C + \phi_n$$
as expected.  Now assume that it holds for all values $\leq m$.  Then for $m + 1$, we have \begin{align}
\phi_{n(m+1)} &= \phi_{n + nm} \\
&\leq C + \phi_n + \phi_{nm}\circ f^n  &\text{ by almost additivity} \\
&\leq C + \phi_n + Cm + \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m-1}(\phi_n \circ f^{nj})\circ f^{n} &\text{ by inductive hypothesis} \\
&= C(m+1) + \phi_n + \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m-1}(\phi_n \circ f^{n(j + 1)}) \\
&= C(m + 1) + \sum\limits_{j = 0}^m \phi_n \circ f^{nj} &\text{ combining terms}
\end{align}

The lower bound works in exactly the same way.